# Getting the longest possible set of rows based on a comparison of two of its columns

Tags: sql

I have a table where I have fields like:

| num_index | num_val | previous_num_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcde1234 | 0 |
| 1 | qwe342asd | 0 |
| 2 | fghij5678 | abcde1234 |
| 2 | t5344dsad | qwe342asd |
| 2 | y54675adz | qwe342asd |
| 3 | klmno5432 | fghij5678 |
| 3 | yuort9971 | t5344dsad |
| 4 | pqrst3232 | klmno5432 |
| 5 | xyzab6t05 | pqrst3232 |

And I want to get the longest set of rows such that
for ANY row with `num_index = n` the value of `num_val` is equal
to the value of `previous_num_val` of row `num index = n - 1`.
My expected output would be:

| num_index | num_val | previous_num_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcde1234 | 0 |
| 2 | fghij5678 | abcde1234 |
| 3 | klmno5432 | fghij5678 |
| 4 | pqrst3232 | klmno5432 |
| 5 | xyzab6t05 | pqrst3232 |

Note that for every `previous_num_val` theres is a row that has a column with an equal `num_val`
and every `num_val` is UNIQUE (primary key)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  And are you passing in `n`?  How is that determined?

Comment: I am using sqlite3, would be a value for the "num_index" column, the condition being that "previous_num_val" of row with "num_index" 3 should be equal to "num_val" of row with "num_index" 2 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You the path using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select num_index, num_val, previous_num_val, cast(num_val as char(10000)) as num_vals, 1 as n
      from t
      where num_index = 5
      union all
      select t.num_index, t.num_val, t.previous_num_val, concat_ws('->', cte.num_vals, t.num_val), n + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.num_index = cte.num_index - 1 and
              t.num_val = cte.previous_num_val
     )
select *
from (select cte.*, max(n) over () as max_n
      from cte
     ) cte
where n = max_n
```

Note that this puts the values in a concatenated string, rather than in separate rows.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae574bb30c089a91f72c651d4f1902f7) is a db<>fiddle (which happens to use MySQL but the code is very similar in SQLite).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is only one path from 5 to 1 that follows the condition that the num of column "n" is equal to the previous_num of column "n+1",
For example one of the results of the fiddle you gave me is:
xyzab6t05->pqrst3232->yuort9971->t5344dsad->abcde1234

but the value "yuort9971" already breaks the condition because the previous_num of the column with "klmno5432" is "fghij5678" and ("fghij5678" !== "yuort9971")

Sorry for the long answer but I'm trying to make myself clear

Comment: @Sassy . . . I get it.  The adjusted answer returns only one row.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, It works now, only issue left is I saw the limit string length is 10k chars, and I need to scale this query for a lot of rows, is there a way to get the result in table format? Because if my path is larger than 1k rows I think the num_vals is going to break ( > 10k chars).
And again, thank you very much for the answer

Comment: @Sassy . . . You are going to have problems with recursive CTEs at some point.  But you can make that limit whatever you want.  I just put in an easy number to type.